# how to combine two objects using path finder in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

i want it to be like this [image]

but when i click the minus front, both objects got cut out like this;

[image]

so how? how do you combine it like in the first picture?

here the 2 original objects before i click minus front;

[image]

Comment: You circled "subtract paths". Is that not what you want to achieve?

Comment: im actually learning a tutorial, but when it comes to this step, my minus front doesnt work exactly like what is shown in the first picture.

Comment: Can you show the image just before your ideal outcome? What are the two original objects?

Comment: You can't get to your results from the (no 3) image above them. There must be more paths there originally.

Comment: thats what i wonder must click on something else first but idk what im new to this software.

Comment: help me ejjejcoqkslajiewe

Comment: Who was the goose that down voted this question? It's a VERY good question.

Answer (score 2):

The `Pathfinder` Toolset is very good for some tasks, but it's not the only boolean operator in Illustrator. The `Shape Builder Tool` (<kbd>Shift+M</kbd> by default) is what I would recommend in this case.

If you hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, you can delete the sections of lines that are between intersections of selected Items.

[image: Deleting lines between intersections of selected Items with the Shape Builder Tool]

Comment: I love Shape Builder! Worth mentioning that your answer is only applicable to CS5+ as a result, though... using Pathfinder is more backwards compatible as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I post an answer instead of comment because I use pictures.

If I had the picture as you and needed to create the picture you need I'd do the follows:

[image]

Select the upper shape and click

Object->Path->Divide Objects Below

I've got this picture -

[image]

After I join the two selected triangles in pathfinder by pressing Join button and this is the final image -

[image]

remember, that your question could be marked as unclear by moderators.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is really good for this sort of drawing

When not in 'Object Drawing mode', Flash will automatically treat all intersections of lines and fills in the same malleable way the Path Finder tool operates.

If your objects are already grouped, just break them apart to 'flatten' them into lines and fills.

Once everything is 'flattened' in the same layer, you can use the Selection Tool to adjust intersection points, remove line segments, pull bends in lines, delete fills, etc. You can double-click a line to select all connected lines or double click a fill to select all surrounding lines.

Comment: Hey Charlie could you explain why flash is good for this and how you might do it? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use divide pathfinder and then ungroup using Ctrl + Shift + G and then delete the other objects.